# Question on Split usage in Perl

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, split, concatenation

I wrote an small script to use `split()` as this,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $fh = \*DATA; 


while(my $line = <$fh>) 
{ 
    my @values = split(':', $line);

    foreach my $val (@values) {

      print "$val\n";
    }
} 

__DATA__   
1 : Hello World String10 : NO : A1B2,B3
11 : Hello World String11 : YES : A11B2,B3,B14,B25
```

`A1B2,B3` and `A11B2,B3` are characters form like Only One Letter `A` and One or Two Number `2`, `3`, `14`,`25` etc then concatenated with Only One Letter `B` and one or two Numbers like `2`, `3`, `14`,`25`. etc

Now out put as this

```
1
 Hello World String10
 NO
 A1B2,B3

11
 Hello World String11
 YES
 A11B2,B3,B14,B25
```

How can I hold the last array member from `@values` and made concatenation and out put as this.

```
1
 Hello World String1
 NO
 A1B2,A1B3

11
 Hello World String11
 YES
 A11B2,A11B3,A11B14,A11B25
```

Appreciated for your comments and replies.

[update]

My out put need the concatenation followed the rule.

`A` and one or two numbers and joined by `B` and one or two numbers split by `,`

Comment: The output you give doesn't tie in at all clearly with the inputs in the second case.  What are you really after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
my @values = split(':', $line);
my $a = $values[-1];
$a =~ s/.*(A\d+).*/$1/s;
$values[-1] =~ s/(?<=,)/$a/g;
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/ZwdTx)

Comment: Wow, It's absolutely beyond my knowledge!

Comment: Hello. Could you please give more help about the answer. Assumed that the input segment of `A1B2,B3` Changed to `A1B2,B3 ; A2B2,B3,B4`. And I still wish the output form as following `A1B2,A1B3,A2B2,A2B3,A2B4`. There are two (or more than two *A* members) `A1` and `A2`, and interval symbol is `;`. How to cover it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear how what you ask would apply in even slightly different cases, but here's my attempt.  Before printing @values, do

```
$values[-1] =~ s/(?<=,)/ substr($values[-1],0,3) /ge;
```

Comment: I tested. It out put as this, `A1B2, A1 A1 A1 A1B3` and `A11B2, A1 A1 A1 A1B3, A1 A1 A1 A1B14, A1 A1 A1 A1B25`. Actually, I want the out put `A1B2, A1B3` and `A11B2, A1B3, A1B14, A1B25`. How can I obsolete these no meaning `A1` based on your input? Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how what I wrote could ever do what you show there, but my code won't work with your updated example, so use codaddicts.